# SQL: distinct result columns for where clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a MySQL query which results in distinct columns for each WHERE clause. 
Like an alias for them. 
Let's say I have a table with a column and some arbitrary data, strings for instance.

```
Id | Column1
0  | mango
1  | porcupine 
2  | bear
...
```

I need a query that yields something like:

```
    animals  | fruits
------------------------
0| porcupine | 
1| bear      | mango
```

if that's even possible. I've tried JOIN-ing subqueries, or UNION them, but that just overwrote the results, which is no good..

I will use it in PHP, and check if the aliased column is set, so I can identify that row as such. 
e.g.

```
if( isset($results[$i]["animals"]) ) echo "hey it's an animal, not an apple, feed it!";
```

EDIT: ...I want a query that puts animals and fruits into a distinct columns in the result. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE Column1 = 'porcupine' ) as porcupines
 JOIN (
 SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE Column1 = 'mango' ) as fruits
```

but it wasn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: how do you know from the input data what is a animal and what is a fruit?

Comment: And how do you know that 'not apple' goes with bear and not with porcupine?

Answer (score 0):

create another column (**Column2**)on your table to identify if **Column 1** is a fruit or an animal then create the query:

```
SELECT id, column1 AS [Animal] FROM TABLE
WHERE Column2 = "Animal"
UNION
SELECT ID, column1 AS [Fruit] FROM TABLE
WHERE Column2 = "Fruit"
```

Comment: see, that's the problem, I can't. I have to create a query that figures it out from one column. I can only proved the query with the info what falls under what category, then it should sort those into distinct columns in the result. I wonder if that's even possible.